# Настройка url для каталога yii2

Tags: yii2, чпу

Есть контроллер `Catalog` и его экшн `index`, который отображает каталог. Есть 3 фильтра, по которым пользователь может получить элементы этого каталога - type, model и category. Фильтры все верхнего уровня и никак не вложены и не зависят друг от друга. Они могут быть заданы в url в любом порядке, может быть задано сразу 3 или допустим 1 фильтр. Примеры: catalog/type/2, catalog/category/1/type/3/model/777
Помогите настроить urlManager таким образом, чтобы можно было правильно принять эти фильтры в независимости от порядка или их количества, чтобы элемент массива GET соответствовал значению, то есть чтобы здесь catalog/category/1/type/3/model/777 `$_GET['type']` был равен 3
В первом yii такая задача решалась если в конфиге прописать `'urlFormat'=>'path'` и вот такое правило `'<controller>/<action>/*'=>'<controller>/<action>'`

Answer (score 2):

С условием независимостью от порядка решить задачу невозможно. Нельзя определить что такое `foo` и `bar` в случае различного порядка `/foo/bar/` или `/bar/foo`.

Корректное решение это выделить определенный порядок, с произвольным количеством.

Например, `/category/foo/type/bar`. Настройка UrlManager в вашем случае будет следующей:

```
'<controller:(catalog)>/category/<categoryId:\d+>/type/<typeId:\d+>/model/<modelId:\d+>' => 'catalog/index',
'<controller:(catalog)>/category/<categoryId:\d+>/type/<typeId:\d+>' => 'catalog/index',
'<controller:(catalog)>/category/<categoryId:\d+>' => 'catalog/index',
'<controller:(catalog)>' => 'catalog/index',
```

В случае различных вариантов (тип без категории, или модель без типа) нужно будет прописать все варианты, либо расширить реализацию компонента UrlManager.